# How to dynamically set shadow in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I would like to dynamically set the shadow of a custom marker icon at runtime, because I want to emphasize the currently clicked icon.  I'm using Leaflet 1.0.  Things I've tried:

- Adding a shadow at runtime with the [`createShadow` function](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-createshadow)
- Adding a blank png shadow image to the custom icon and changing it at runtime by either the `createShadow` function or directly modifying the shadow's image source

Here's some psuedocode:

```
function addMyShadow(marker) {
  /* try Leaflet's `createShadow` function */

  // directly modify marker: Uncaught TypeError: marker.createShadow is not a function
  marker.createShadow('lib/images/shadow.png'); 

  // the createShadow is available under options.icon, 
  // but this doesn't seem to change anything
  marker.options.icon.createShadow('lib/images/shadow.png'); 

  /* try directly modifying the shadow's image source */

  // Successfully changes the `currectSrc` property,
  // but also doesn't do anything to the icon on the map
  marker._shadow.currentSrc = 'lib/images/shadow.png'; 
}
```

- I also tried appending a custom class with `-webkit-filter: drop-shadow`, but I'm already using `-webkit-filter` to color a set of icons.  I only want to change the selected icon, not the entire class.  Apparently nesting `-webkit-filter` overwrites the outside `-webkit-filter` instead of stacking filters.  So this isn't a viable option for me.
- Currently I'm experimenting with adding a custom class that uses css `drop-shadow`; it seems like I can manually change the class at runtime, but I'm hoping there's some better built-in way to add a shadow.  It's also not very pretty, because it makes the shadow square even if the image has transparency.

**EDIT:** I want the marker to be draggable (and have the shadow follow as the marker is dragged).  So any solution with two icons would need to bind both icons together somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have 2 L.icon objects: one without shadow and one with a shadow.

To show the shadow, you just switch L.Icon

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {
  if(selectedMarker) {
    if(selectedMarker !== e.target) { // selected marker is NOT this one
      selectedMarker.setIcon(greenIcon);
      e.target.setIcon(greenIconWithShadow);
      selectedMarker = e.target;
    }
    else {   // selected marker is this one
      selectedMarker.setIcon(greenIcon);
      selectedMarker = false;
    }
  }
  else {  // no marker selected
    selectedMarker = e.target;
    e.target.setIcon(greenIconWithShadow);
  }
});
```

The shadow is part of the L.Icon and should follow when dragged

See example http://plnkr.co/edit/PNxzJqMbcRTuo0jWPGyj?p=preview

Comment: I thought about this, but I want to have the marker draggable.  Do you have ideas how to bind two markers together?

Comment: That is a very nice solution.  Thank you for clarifying, and for the example code.